# Как использовать MTProto в Telethon на Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Начал написание своего клиента для Telegram
Не могу понять, как использовать MTProxy или MTProto при создании клиента вызовом TelegramClient.

В документации по Telethon сказнано

> proxy (tuple | list | dict, optional):
>   An iterable consisting of the proxy info. If connection is one of MTProxy, then it should contain MTProxy credentials: ('hostname', port, 'secret'). Otherwise, it’s meant to store function parameters for PySocks, like (type, 'hostname', port). See https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks#usage-1 for more.
>   https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telethon.client.html#telethon-client

Не понятно что за такое 'secret' - это ключи закрытый? или просто пароль фраза придуманная наобум? Если ключ, то где его взять? Да и правильно ли я код пишу?

Вот код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
import socks

api_id = 12356
api_hash = '54654646456ХХХХ45645'
DC1_ip ='149.ХХХ.ХХХ.40' #указан в Available MTProto servers в Test configuration
DC_port = 443
client = TelegramClient('session_name_1', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(DC1_ip,DC_port,'secret'))
client.start()
```

Вот что в логе:

```
 File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\PycharmProjects\TelCliBot\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\socks.py", line 100, in wrapper
 return function(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\PycharmProjects\TelCliBot\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\socks.py", line 832, in connect
 super(socksocket, self).connect(proxy_addr)
 TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91716/discussion-on-question-by-viktor---mtproto--telethon--python).

Comment: (если кто надумает писать ответ, там в чате докопались до причин проблемы, почитайте)

Answer (score 1):

Получилось так: 
1. Пока Telethon работает только с MTProto, которые предлагают 32 символьный secret, есть много ботов в самом телеграмме, один из таких MTProto Proxies. Если в вашем секрете первые буквы "dd" - значит нужно искать другой proxy.
2. Стабильной официальной сборки Telethon, залитой в репозиторий пока нет, но можно качнуть с gitHub.
3. Код для подключения:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection
api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
DC1_ip = '149.XXX.XXX.40'
DC_port = 443
# https://t.me/proxy?server=Ritmseda.online&port=50&ref_secret- 
# share=@mtprotoproxies&secret=5421e99c282e878cea1839bc1a252971
proxy_ip = 'proxy.digitalresistance.dog'
proxy_port = 443
secret = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
proxy = (proxy_ip, proxy_port, secret)
client = TelegramClient('session_name_1', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(proxy_ip, 
proxy_port, secret),  connection=connection.tcpmtproxy.ConnectionTcpMTProxy)
client.session.set_dc(1, DC1_ip, DC_port)
client.start()
```

Спасибо @andreymal

Comment: Ошибка - 'telethon.network.connection.tcpmtproxy' has no attribute 'ConnectionTcpMTProxy' решается использованием - connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте параметр True как гласит документация

```
proxy=(DC1_ip,DC_port, True,'secret'))
```