# Как обойти блокировку telegram для применения библиотеки telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

#Вставляем api_id и api_hash
api_id = "свой код"
api_hash = "свой код"


with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
```

При испрользовании библиотеки telethon для отправки сообщения в чат, выводит ошибку:
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

Comment: Как - как... 
VPN, прокси, что вам удобнее

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужен прокси для доступа к Telegram, вам нужно установить [PySocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks#installation), а затем изменить:

`TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)`

на

`TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 4444))`

[Источник](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html#signing-in-behind-a-proxy) и [на всякий случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962679/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-mtproto-%D0%B2-telethon-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)

Comment: импортировал библиотеку import socks, заменил на with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '174.70.241.18', 24404)) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))  но та же история