# MTProxy для TelegramClient библиотека Telethon как пользоваться proxy

Tags: python, telethon

Допустим. У меня есть проксик -
https://t.me/proxy?server=To--Too--To.to--Too--to.tk&port=2590&secret=3fQ1mpsyX_HR5QhN8OD3U3s
или
https://t.me/proxy?server=168.119.182.51&port=88&secret=ee00000000000000000000000000000000646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d

И пытаюсь подключиться:

```
import asyncio

from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, connection
from telethon.errors import FloodWaitError

proxy = ('FIRSTLY--00--FIRSTLY.firstly--00--firstly.tk',2590,'3fQ1mpsyX_HR5QhN8OD3U3s')

number = {
  "api_id": "2229909",
  "api_hash": "54cccd7d67d89a8473e6f9ea95bf3454",
  "session": "1ApWapzMBu1QoyL1As7fuvuwsrxLK9PU8SuTH8hk-Me7dAt0E1mGVOIHBak3eXVpWqzaA0l6PPpRPLCpUkIkUolB6rWU8y8eZg87RuCqBRRcxtGquaSLSUo5EQxS_tX-SdyflDod2b8v3pkFt_pmCNyCWnPjqgkOgEPLmeiLMJBCllgnK49Jiyr7IGS8XyWt_xHUELPUptK-14oRRZ1YHbARt87ibzqjH7OEKB8uReN4sImeYJxO17D_Tlgr-p5zF8epRkPuYZUzBxXXsQ9pVwDiPO8LmlQp3NRICoDSMAuhRbJMWLOPs16h664GpwEoDHBAZbeYGmVNTupmxLJMXTbPsZxYXrLE="
}

with TelegramClient(
            session=StringSession(number['session']),
            api_id=number['api_id'],
            api_hash=number['api_hash'],
            device_model="Desktop",
            system_version="Windows 10",
            app_version="1.0",
            connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate,
            proxy=proxy) as client:

    client.send_message('cashriser', 'hello world')
```

А ему не нравится:

```
tcpmtproxy.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._secret = bytes.fromhex(proxy[2])
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 2
```

Comment: Я нашел прекрасное решение 1го вопроса на другом языке  (long value = new BigInteger("d1bc4f7154ac9edb", 16).longValue();). Как на Python это решить?

Comment: Первое - `int("d1bc4f7154ac9edb", 16)`. Второе похоже на Base64, но не гарантирую что это оно.

Comment: @ДмитрийБовак, приведите весь код ошибки

Comment: отследите по трейсбеку какой параметр не нравиться модулю tcpmtproxy.py.Попробуйте другой параметр.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/964047/234134

Answer (score 0):

Из вашей не полностью показанной ошибки видно, что в `proxy`, по втором элементе не число в 16-ричном виде, так как у вас там буква 'Q', вот в `proxy=proxy) as client:`

Может просто в нем указать данные в немного другом формате? В 16-ричном? Просто я в ботах не разбираюсь. Но там явно видно что в proxy надо указать 3-ий элемент в 16-чном числе!?

---

### Upgrade:

Библиотека для ботов поддерживает только 2 тип проксика, так как там 16-ричный пароль `secret`.

```
proxy = ('168.119.182.51',88,'ee00000000000000000000000000000000646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d')
```

Может надо обновить `number`?

Comment: @insolor, я исправил

Comment: Теперь у вас код отличается от кода из вопроса ровно одной строкой (там где настройки прокси). Какой смысл копировать остальное?